# Proper constructor for custom class

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, c++03

I'm currently using a custom object to represent the nodes of a graph. The graph is just a vector of such object.

```
class node {
public:
   unsigned int vertex;
   unsigned int weight;
   bool operator< (const node &x){ return weight < x.weight; }
   bool operator> (const node &x){ return weight > x.weight; }
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to come up with a proper constructor when I need to push_back() such object.

```
unsigned int u, v, w;
vector<node> G[V];
G[u-1].push_back({v-1, w});
```

This is the only way it works, but just with C++11. Is there a standard way to do that? If I try to compile with g++ without using the C++11 flag I get errors.
I'm basically trying to implement an **emplace_back()**.

EDIT:
**I need to compile my code with older version of C++**

Comment: Just with c++11, c++14, c++17...

Comment: Yeah, I meant that. But I'd like to find a way that works for older version too, if it's possible

Comment: OK, so you should say "I can only use C++03" or something to that effect.

Comment: What's wrong with a two argument consttuctor that initializes the members? Is that what you're asking for or something else?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to construct such object that work with older version of C++ too, for example C++98

Comment: It's still not clear what you want since constructors are such a basic concept it feels like you're not looking for the obvious solution: `node (int vertex_, int weight_) : vertex(vertex_), weight(weight_) {}` `v.push_back(node(v-1, w));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is the only way it works, but just with C++11.

And that's great, since that's the current state. Moreover this should work with C++14, C++17 and so on probably, thus you are on the safe side.

---

BTW, I guess that `G[u-1].push_back({v-1, w});` is just a sample, since `u` is uninitialised, which is critical, let alone the other variables.

---

> I was looking for a "backward compatibility" solution.

Define a constructor like this for example:

```
node(unsigned int v, unsigned int w) : vertex(v), weight(w) {}
```

and then do:

```
G[u - 1].push_back(node(v-1, w));
```

Comment: Ok, but I was looking for a "_backward compatibility_" solution.